# Im new to role playing games.Where should i start?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, roleplaying

I've played Skyrim but I really want to know where to start for dungeons and dragons.

Comment: Welcome to the stack, Blaine! While you're here, take our brief [tour], and for a more in depth look at how things are run around here, you can browse through the many [help] articles. Additionally, with 20 rep, you can join and participate in our [chat], we've got many people who would be happy to answer your questions there.

Comment: We've marked your question as a dupe because we think it should be entirely covered by the other question. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: There's a question hidden in here though: What is the difference between CRPGs (Balduar's Gate), Morrowind/Oblivion/Skyrim-Likes and P&P-RPGs (such as D&D)